# python and mysql.connector requires quoting of unsigned int

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using mysql connector 1.0.9. and Python 3.2

This query fails due to a syntax error (mysql.connector throws ProgrammingError, the specific MySQL error is just "there is a syntax error to the right of "%(IP)s AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < accessed":

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bad_ip_logins WHERE IP = %(IP)s AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < accessed
```

But if I quote the variable IP, it works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bad_ip_logins WHERE IP = '%(IP)s' AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < accessed
```

In context:

```
IP = 1249764151  # IP converted to an int
conn = mysql.connector.connect(db_params)
curs = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bad_ip_logins WHERE IP = %(IP)s AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < accessed"
params = {'IP', IP}
curs.execute(query, params)
```

My understanding is that you never have to quote variables for a prepared statement (and this is true for every other query in my code, even ones that access the IP variable on this table). Why do I need to quote it in this single instance, and nowhere else?

If this isn't doing a prepared statement I'd be interested in hearing about that as well. I wasn't able to inject anything with this - was it just quoting it in such a way as to prevent that?

If it matters, this is the table description:

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| IP       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_id  | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| accessed | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What is your *Python* code using this statement? What is the full traceback of the exception?

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using a prepared statement with placeholders here? Because this looks exactly like what would happen if you incorrectly used Python's `%` operator, instead of letting MySQL fill in the placeholders. (And this is why we need to see the Python code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use string interpolation. Leave the SQL parameter to the database adapter:

```
cursor.execute('''\
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bad_ip_logins WHERE IP = %s AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) < accessed''', (ip,))
```

Here, we pass the parameter `ip` in to the `execute()` call as a separate parameter (in a tuple, to make it a sequence), and the database adapter will take care of proper quoting, filling in the `%s` placeholder.